# Make a context free grammar not ambiguous

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I have a test this week. There is the following grammar for Boolean statements:

```
B -> B and B | not B | (B) | id
```

`B` is a non terminal, and the terminals are: `and`, `not`, `(`, `)`, `id`

This grammar is ambiguous. I need to re-write it and create an equivalent grammar which is not ambiguous and without left recursion, such that `not` is in high precedence, 'and' is associative to the left.

I have tried to do it by myself: my beginning was:

```
B -> not B' | ( B' | id B'
```

but I think this is wrong and I am really stuck for a long time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'ambiguous'? The initial grammar permits a choice of substitution and your proposal permits substitution as well. Please clarify.

Comment: ambiguous means that there are 2 parsing tree for one word in the language. for exmaple the word: a and b and c , has 2 parsing trees

Comment: @Codor looks ambiguous because `not A and B` could mean either `not (A and B)` or `(not A) and B`, there are no precedence rules in the initial grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using more non-terminals allows setting precedence on all operators (I hope I'm getting the notation you're using right).

This is to get right-to-left associativity for and: id and id and id is parsed as id and [id and id]

```
B -> NotExpr | NotExpr and B
NotExpr -> PrimaryExpr | not NotExpr
PrimaryExpr -> id | (B)
```

This is to get left-to-right associativity for and: id and id and id is parsed as [id and id] and id

```
B -> NotExpr | B and NotExpr
NotExpr -> PrimaryExpr | not NotExpr
PrimaryExpr -> id | (B)
```

Comment: The precedence is real: for example, "not id and id" can only be parsed as "[not id] and id" and not as "not [id and id]" because "id and id" is not a PrimaryExpr. Adding a non-terminal for each precedence level all the way down to a primary expression, and then back up with parentheses is a typical way that grammars are built, see the XQuery grammar for example.

Comment: @GhislainFourny how do you set the grammar to be associative to the left? what is the rule?

Comment: I'm never sure how "to the left" and "to the right" map to left-to-right or right-to-left associativity, because I tend to use the latter terminology. But basically, "NotExpr and B" on line 1 forces to associate as in "id and (id and id)" (right-to-left), while "B and NotExpr" would force to associate as in "(id and id) and id" (left-to-right). You can adapt it in the answer to pick the variant you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be the following (after edit, thanks @Peter):

```
B  -> not B | B'
B' -> ( B ) | B' and B | id
```

Comment: Nonsense. You can only get one NOT.